# Is there a way to set a MKMapView map to an alpha lower to 1 and its markers to 1?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'd like to have a map that is faded, but with full-opacity markers. Is this possible?

I've set the map to 0.5 opacity in my XIB, but don't see a way to change the alpha programmatically (to the marker being added or the viewForAnnotation method).